# previous quarters in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Forgive me I tried several searches here and other places in general but cant seem to fix issue I am having at the moment. Can someone please help me figure out?

I am trying to find quarter strings from inputdate in JavaScript. For "01/31/2009" it should give Q1,2013 Q4,2012 etc based on offset given as input parameter. when offset is 0 then current quarter, 1 then previous, 2 then previous 2 quarter etc...

my current code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPmf2/)

```
function getQuarterStrings(id) {
    var d = new Date();
    var d = new Date("01/31/2009");
    var str;
    switch (id) {
...
}
```

Remaining code is in jsfiddle. As you can see, it fails on second last condition even though everything seems ok. Please help me figure out my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Tip: Debug with console.log(), not alert()

Comment: thanks! I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your comparisons are off, and `Date` tries to compensate for months that don't have as many days when you `setMonth`. This code should work:

```
function getQuarterStrings(id) {
    var d = new Date("03/31/2009");
    d.setDate(1);
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - id * 3);
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var quarter = Math.ceil(month / 3);
    return ("Q" + quarter + ", " + year);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Above code changes work for all dates I tried. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

This works, and is a lot more concise. It also allows you to use any offset instead of a limited set of values:

```
function getQuarterStrings(date, id) {
    // quarter is 0-based here
    var quarter = Math.floor(date.getMonth() / 3),
        year = date.getFullYear();
    quarter -= id;

    if(quarter < 0) {
        var yearsChanged = Math.ceil(-quarter / 4);
        year -= yearsChanged;
        // Shift quarter back to a nonnegative number
        quarter += 4 * yearsChanged;
    }

    return "Q" + (quarter + 1) + ", " + year;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dPmf2/6/

Comment: I am sorry but code doesnt work for date "03/31/2009". Potentially same issue that I faced originally.

Comment: @user704988 Ok, that's because changing the date by 3 months isn't a reliable way of changing quarters. The key is to figure out the quarter first and then calculate based on that. Please try my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get rid of the switch statement by doing this:

```
function getQuarterStrings(id) {
    var d = new Date();
    var d = new Date("01/31/2009");
    var str;
    if (id !== 0){
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3*id);
    }
    str = getQuarter(d);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This is good, but results are still wrong. Doesnt work for "03/31/2014"